# Prove that the only automorphism of order 2 of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is $m \mapsto -m$ for $q = 3$ and $q = 5$ and $q = 7$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

My assignment asks me to prove that the only automorphism of order 2 of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is $m \mapsto -m$ for $q = 3$ and $q = 5$ and $q = 7$. I have been stuck for ages, and now I wonder if it is true. I need some help to get started. This is my attempt: Assume $k$ and $q$ are relative prime (this is necessary otherwise $\phi$ is not an automorphism), then:
$$
m = \phi^2(m) = k^2m \implies k^2 \equiv 1 \mod q
$$
But I don't know how to go on from there. I cant see that $k = -1$ is the only option.

Comment: Is $q=p^n$ a power of a prime?

Comment: No it is the case that we have exactly $q = 3$ or $q=5$ or $q=7$. We are only interested in these 3 cases.

Comment: I have read your title as "Prove that the only automorphism of order $2$ is for $q=3,5,7$. So you mean:" Let $2<q<10$ be a prime. Show that ...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $k^2\equiv 1 \bmod p$, then $(k-1)(k+1)\equiv 0 \bmod p$. That is the reason why there are only $2$ options.

In general we can do these sort of things in any integer domain.( polynomials cant have more roots than their degree)

Comment: Also here $q$ need not be prime.

Comment: In general one has that the automorphism group of $\mathbb Z_n$ Is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$ and this one can be calculated via the chinese remainder theorem and the theorem for existence of primitive roots. (and the theorem that $\mathbb Z_{2^n}\cong \mathbb Z^{2n-2}\mathbb Z_2$ for powers of $2$ above 4.

Comment: Can you prove why $(k-1)(k+1) \equiv 0 \mod p \implies k = \pm 1 $? How do we know that $k$ is not some big number, for example? This isn't clear to me. I am not very good at modular arithmetic

Comment: well yeah, if $(k-1)(k+1)$ is a multiple of $p$ then $p$ divides $k-1$ or $p$ divides $(k+1)$. You dont need modular arithmetic, its just euclids lemma.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear to me that it means $p$ divides $k-1$ or $p$ divides $k+1$. But how does this imply that $k = \pm 1$?

Comment: To avoid possible confusion you really need to say that $p$ is prime (otherwise there could be more than two options). I know there is a tendency to assume that all integers denoted by $p$ are prime, but it is not really a good idea!

Comment: @MariusJonsson the definition of $x\equiv a \bmod p$ is that $p$ divides $x-a$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* When $q$ is prime, $ k^2 \equiv 1 \bmod q \iff  k \equiv \pm1 \bmod q$. What is the order of $x \mapsto kx$ when $k=1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For $q$ prime, $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is a field, so $k^2-1=0$ there has only two solutions, $k=1$ or $k=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

You're right that $k=-1$ is a possibility, since $k^2\equiv_q 1$ (you also know that there are atmost two values $k$ can have, since $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is a field). Remember that if $k=1$, i.e, $m\mapsto m$ then the order of the automorphism is $1$, not $2$.